# Python shell - new line

Tags: python, django, shell

I'm following a tutorial in a book and I'm having some issues with the "\n".

Here is the code that I am asked to type in Python shell:

```
from django.template import Template, Context

template = Template(
    '{{ ml.exclaim }}!\n'
    'she said {{ ml.adverb }}\n'
    'as she jumped into her convertible {{ ml.noun1 }}\n'
    'and drove off with her {{ ml.noun2 }}.\n'
)

mad_lib = {
    'exclaim':'Ouch',
    'adverb':'dutifully',
    'noun1':'boat',
    'noun2':'pineapple',
}

context = Context({'ml': mad_lib})
template.render(context)
```

So whenever I enter this into the Python shell, it comes returns it as this all at once:

```
u'Ouch!\nshe said dutifully\nas she jumped into her convertible boat\nand drove off with her pineapple.\n'
```

I'd like to have it come out like this all on separate lines:

```
Ouch!
she said dutifully
as she jumped into her convertible boat
and drove off with her pineapple.
```

All help is appreciated.

Comment: `print template.render(context)`

Comment: Templates take in HTML so you can safely use `<br/>` instead of `\n`

Comment: There is no html involved, why is everyone answering about <br>

Answer (score 0):

strings that appeared next to each other is automatically combined together in python, so

```
>>> s1 = "hello " "world"
>>> s2 = "hello world"
>>> s3 = "hello"
..."world" \
>>> s1 == s2 == s3
True
```

your rendered string is the exact result you should expect.
but, I think you are just asking how to make `\n` actually breaks a line,
just use `print template.render(context)`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `autoescape template tag` to esacpe HTML linebreak (< br />) characters.

In addition, since you do not have html `linebreak` characters, you have to convert your text file newlines to HTML `linebreaks`, using the `linebreaksbr` `Django template filte`r, as suggested in [this][1] answer.

**Note**:-It will works when you try to print direct in html.